# Changing color of a php return value

Tags: php, html, css

My index.php

```
    <li> 
        <a class="tag">[<?php the_category(' ');?>]</a> //this is the problem line        
        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">                  
           <span><?php the_title();?></span>
        </a>
    </li>
```

My CSS:

```
.tag {color: rgba(140, 140, 140, 255);}
```

This is how it looks like:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuoI1.png)

This is how its supposed to look like:[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vmj0I.png)

I new to php and i have no idea what to try.
Thanks you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #000;
}

.tag {color: rgba(140, 140, 140, 255);}
```

```html
<li> 
    <a class="tag">[TAG]</a>
    <a href="#">                  
       <span>TITLE</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Looks good to me. There has to be another css-rule, which overrides your rule. Use the dev-tools of your browser to see which one. [ctrl]+[shift]+c in chome. Then click on your element and inspect "Styles" on the right side.

[image]

You also may want to have a look at [css-specifity](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp).

Comment: You were right! There was a overlaping ccs code. I fixed it thanks alot!

Comment: @noober No problemo :) - Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).